# How to Install Xcode Command Line Tools, Mac

Tags: xcode, command, installation, line

I have problem with installing a program and it says that I will need to be promted to install Xcode Command Line Tools. How do I install that?

Answer (score 7):

From Terminal execute `xcode-select --install`